# Conditional joining in a list

Tags: python, list, string-concatenation

I have a Python list:

```
data = ['Cost', '$', 4244, '$', 4090, '$', 3967]
```

What I want to do is merge the `$` with preceding element and obtain a new list:

```
data = ['Cost', '$4244', '$4090', '$3967']
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Are the elements after the `'$'` string always integers?

Comment: is `[data[0]]+[(data[i]+str(data[i+1])) for i in range(1, len(data), 2)]` what you want?

Comment: @HarvIpan the list is mixed interger/string values, you need str() arround the numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make use of [*iterators*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator):

```
data_iter = iter(data)
[e + str(next(data_iter)) if e == '$' else e for e in data_iter]
```

This makes use of the fact we can obtain the next element of an iterable, even while looping over the iterable. Each time a `'$'` string is found, the next element is pulled in and concatenated as a string.

Demo:

```
>>> data = ['Cost', '$', 4244, '$', 4090, '$', 3967]
>>> data_iter = iter(data)
>>> [e + str(next(data_iter)) if e == '$' else e for e in data_iter]
['Cost', '$4244', '$4090', '$3967']
```